# How to get twilio phone rental rates via API

Tags: twilio

I'm writing an application that needs to rent numbers via the API, but I need to know the rental rates of the phone before I rent a number. Is this possible via the API? I saw a lot of info on voice rates and sms rates via csv files etc. but nothing on the rentals.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

You can find a pricing sheet for phone numbers here:

https://www.twilio.com/resources/rates/international-phone-number-rates.csv

Its linked off of the Voice page on twilio.com:

https://www.twilio.com/voice/pricing

Hope that helps.